# How to set Home Page ONLY HTML code in Header

Tags: php, html, wordpress, header

I have more or less completed the design for my website (built in Wordpress) and I have a slider in my header.php that currently shows on every page. I would like for this to only appear on my homepage - I've got to think there is an easy snippet of code to implement that can either check for a home page argument or page specific URL or something that only uses this code on that page.

Here is my slider code, currently in header.php, that I would like to have in some sort of argument structure that only pops on the homepage. Hoping someone has the key!

```
<div class="art-pageslider">

     <div class="art-shapes">
            </div>
<div class="art-slider art-slidecontainerpageslider" data-width="930" data-height="200">
    <div class="art-slider-inner">
<div class="art-slide-item art-slidepageslider0">


</div>
<div class="art-slide-item art-slidepageslider1">


</div>
<div class="art-slide-item art-slidepageslider2">


</div>
<div class="art-slide-item art-slidepageslider3">


</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="art-slidenavigator art-slidenavigatorpageslider" data-left="0" data-top="1">
<a href="#" class="art-slidenavigatoritem"></a><a href="#" class="art-slidenavigatoritem"></a><a href="#" class="art-slidenavigatoritem"></a><a href="#" class="art-slidenavigatoritem"></a>
</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [is_front_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) to test if you are in the index template

```
<?php if( is_front_page() ): ?>

   <!-- your slide code -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page):

```
<?php if(is_front_page() ) { ?>
    <!-- Slider HTML Code Here -->
<?php } ?>
```

#### From Wordpress Codex:

> If you are using a static page as your front page, this is useful:
>
> ```
> <title>
> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> &raquo; <?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(); ?>
> </title>
> ```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this presumes the OP has a static frontpage set, `if(is_front_page() || is_home() )` would cover all bases

Comment: I downvoted this, as you have kept inside PHP code. If the OP were to simply copy and paste his code in place of your comment, he would be get syntax errors.

Comment: @Lee I changed the answer. Can you please check?

Comment: Yeah that's fine, it's what every other answer here shows.

Comment: Yes I know, but thinking about it you supplied info from the codex actually, so I'll replace the downvote. Sorry for annoyance.

Comment: What you said might be right. I will take it in a positive sense. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

```
<?php if(is_front_page() ) { ?>
   // your HTML here
<?php } ?>
```